# Mean of a Pandas Panel

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a Pandas Panel `a` that looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2985 (items) x 15 (major_axis) x 15 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 1959-07-05 00:00:00 to 2016-09-11 00:00:00
Major_axis axis: bobl to wheat
Minor_axis axis: bobl to wheat
```

If I take a single slice, like this: `a.iloc[2900].mean()` and calculate the mean, I get what I'm looking for (a pandas Series).

If I take the whole panel, and do this `a.mean(axis=1)`, I get something that has the right shape (2985 x 15), but strange numbers (including `inf`).

**How can I do the operation I did for the single slice, but for all 2985 items?**

Comment: Any reason you are using a `Panel`?  They will be deprecated in future pandas releases.

Comment: how does the iterated mean of the means compare to the weird looking mean you get

Comment: @pylang - this is what I get from doing a rolling correlation matrix on my data.

Comment: @Julius The iterated means are exactly what I'm looking for, the mean in the respective axis of the 15x15 matrix, which is a Series of 1x15. The Panel mean has the right dimensions (2985 x 15) but numbers I don't recognise.